# Perl package is installed but still see error

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

I have just installed the package in my system using the instructions described in [the question *"How to install .pm to run the perl script"*](/q/20671787)

Now, I am trying to  run the Perl script But I still see the following error:

```
Win32::OLE operating in debugging mode: _Unique => 1
 at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Win32/OLE/Lite.pm line 30
        require Win32/OLE/Lite.pm called at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Win32/OLE.pm line 48
        require Win32/OLE.pm called at C:\Users\c_desaik\Desktop\pwrdb\offtarget\pwrdb.pl line 37
        main::BEGIN() called at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Win32/OLE/Lite.pm line 0
        eval {...} called at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Win32/OLE/Lite.pm line 0
main::(C:\Users\c_desaik\Desktop\pwrdb\offtarget\pwrdb.pl:53):

53:     my $prod_id = "QPSTAtmnServer.Application";
  DB<1>
```

I can actually see the OLE.PM file at the location `C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Win32/OLE` but still it is throwing an error.

I did not copy the module, I installed it using CPAN.

I am confused because there are two locations where I see an `OLE` folder

- `C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib`
- `C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Win32/OLE`

Normally, when I install something, it has only one root directory. I am not sure why Perl is operated from two of those.

Comment: That isn't the complete error message. Please show the result of running your program without debug

Comment: If you have `OLE.pm` at `C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Win32/OLE` then something is wrong. Did you copy it there?

Comment: I did not copy it there. I installed it using CPAN. I am also confused because there are two locations where i do see OLE folder 1.C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib and 2. C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Win32/OLE. Normally, when we install something, it has one root directory. I am not sure why Perl is operated from two of those.

Comment: This question is very confused. There is no reason why there shouldn't be more than one `OLE` directory - they are not necessarily related. I have tried to edit your question so that it makes sense, but error message you show is corrupt and incomplete. Please run your program without debug and show the output as I asked.

Comment: OK. You are right. When I run the script in without -d then it runs fine and comes back saying that I need to add some more parameters. BUT not sure what it is saying in -d mode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Win32::OLE operating in debugging mode" is not an error. It's a warning that's issued when a script using Win32::OLE is run from the debugger. Everything is functioning as it should.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have *both* [DWIM Perl](http://dwimperl.com/) *and* [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) installed on the same Windows machine. Unless you need to use both simultaneously, then you should *uninstall* the one you aren't using.

To get things working again you may need to uninstall *both* versions of Perl and reinstall your preferred brand.